# Generate outline polygon of a point respectively raster data set

Tags: python, geopandas, shapely, rasterio

***background***:
I have given multiple large text files representing points and elevation (X,Y,Z). At a larger step I will combine into one large mosaiced DEM.

***goal***:
To indicate each datasets point extent I'm searching for an elegant and fast way to generate the exact outline of each pointdataset separately. I came across geopandas.GeoSeries.convex_hull, but that hull does not represent the exact extent but rather the connection of the farthest located points as the following image illustrates:

[image]

What I am for - the outline Polygon - should not include those areas highlighted in green, which are actually not covered by point information, but part of the convex hull.

***current approach***:

```
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd

#import file
df=pd.read_csv('test01.txt',sep='\s')

#generate points from xyz
points01=gpd.GeoDataFrame(df,geometry=gpd.points_from_xy(df.X, df.Y))

#option 1 (convex hull)
points01_hull = points01.unary_union.convex_hull
points01_hull
```

Is there any geospatial method within Python (GeoPandas etc.) to obtain such an outline polygon based on point information or would it be easier to convert the point to a rasterdataset maintaining the initial point data resolution and process the outline of the raster dataset instead?

Comment: Please clarify what you expect. Because what is shown here (in green) IS the convex hull of your points. Do you want an intersection with the rectangles ? Or the full extent ?

Comment: What have you tried because unless you add a Python code attempt your question will be closed

Comment: thanks for your comments. I updated the question with a better illustration of what I aim to get and included my current code which yields the illustrated red convex hull. Maybe convex hull is the wrong wording from my side, sorry for that. What I aim for is the exact outline along all the given points.

Comment: That looks like a lot of points! One method, if you can afford a small [`buffer`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#object.buffer), is to add a buffer to all the points and then perform a [`unary_union`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.ops.unary_union) on them all. That would give you a `Polygon` that is slightly larger than your shape. You can take the `exterior` of the polygon to remove the holes. Set `resolution=1` in buffer for a slight efficiency improvement. I think you can shrink the polygon afterward to mitigate the buffer.

Comment: How many points are there?

Comment: It is the [concave-hull polygon](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Classification-of-convex-and-concave-hull-Adapted-from-6_fig5_312373158) or [alpha-shape polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha_shape) of the points and there are many questions/answers on GIS SE